# The name <...> does not exist in the namespace <...>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I found myself stuck in this little problem that seems to have no solution at all. I'm trying to set the `DataContext` to a `Window` in WPF Project that looks like this:

[image]

The XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="CSB.Tasks.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSB.Tasks"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CSB.Tasks.ViewModels.WPF" <!-- This is what i need -->
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="350" 
    Width="525">

<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="{Binding ResizeBorderThickness}"
                  GlassFrameThickness="0"
                  CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}"/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

<StackPanel Margin="5">

</StackPanel>
```

I want to set `WindowViewModel` as the ViewModel of the `Window`, but VS doesn't seem to find the folders where the class is contained. So, when I try to add the `Window.DataContext` like:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:WindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

VS obviously tells me that the class does not exist.

I've been searching for similar questions on SO and I found plenty of them, but no one actually helped me. I already tried restarting VS, cleaning and rebuilding the project, compiling on a specific target platform (now it's set to Any CPU), moving the ViewModel in the root folder and then moving it back, absolutely no changes.

Does anyone know what could the cause be?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you compile even though the designer shows an error?

Comment: @NeilB: If there is a issue with WPF parsing, the Compiler will often re-use the last parsed version wich causes issues with debugging. One of the reasons WPF debugging is harder. So it is a terrible idea to hit compile before the XAML side issues is fixed.

Comment: Sometimes with these issues it's actually easier to just copy everything to a new project from scratch...

Comment: @Christopher you have it backwards. The XAML designer actually uses the last successfully built version of the assembly, and it will tell you there are errors when there aren’t really any. All you need to do is actually compile. Neil B’s advice is good. The compiler/msbuild is very smart about recompiling things when they need to be. The designer not so much.

Comment: @NeilB No, I cannot compile/recompile the project, even after a cleanup and a complete VS restart.

Comment: Double check the namespace in the WindowVeiwModel.cs, try renaming the viewmodel... everything looks like it should work if the namespace in the VM is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to add the `DataContext` to the MainWindow XAML. The namespace of the `ViewModel` was set to `CSB.Tasks` in order to access it globally, but even using the local xmlns I couldn't be able to reference it. I had to change the namespace of the `ViewModel` according to its actual path in the project folder, so:

```
namespace CSB.Tasks.ViewModels.WPF
{
   public class WindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

In order to set the `xmlns:vm` and to use it in the `DataContext` declaration. Then I switched the `ViewModel` namespace back to `CSB.Tasks` and recompiled the project and for some reason in the XAML editor I could be able to access `WindowViewModel` from the `xmlns:local`.

It's not very clear to me if this is a bug or not.

Thank you all for the help!